# c# datetimepicker : how do i get the date in the format? 1/1/2001

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am using winforms, c#, visual studio 2008

the format on the datetimepicker is set to `short` which means that it will just display the date like this `1/1/2001`

however, i am unable to just get that and NOT the time,

for example this:

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString());
```

gives me this:

```
11/4/2010 12:00:00AM
```

how do i get just `11/4/2010`?

Comment: Your title asks for date, your question asks for time - a little confusing at first glance.

Comment: @Ahmad: I made an edit to address your concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For time call `ToShortTimeString()`:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortTimeString()
```

For date call `ToShortDateString()`:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

Example of both:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

Comment: Further information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx in case you need to modify the output.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the format in ToString() function. eg.-

dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ==> gives value "04/11/2010"
or 
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") ==> gives value "04/Nov/2010"

however you may also use **ToShortDateString()** function it will return the date-format set in your computer system.... you may also change that from ControlPanel--> Region and Languages --> Date,Time format to "dd/MM/yyyy" to get "04/11/2010" etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

`.ToShortDateString()` works too and will take the date formatting from your region.

Comment: Nope. It would be M/d/yyyy. MM and dd will put leading 0's.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to enter a format in the ToString method, like so:

> Date.ToString("d-M-yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
```

Comment: Well the question indicates the date picker's format is already set to `short`.