# DataGridView automatically charges TIME if value is a DATE (C# & SQL Server 2008)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I'm new here and develop just for the pleasure (I'm mexican excuse me if my English isn't good enough)

I have noticed that when retrieving a date-value from a DataGridView it automatically adds the time complement (12:00:00 a.m. by default)
Here's an example

Fact #1

I store the value in a SQL Server 2008 table adding this line to my query

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

(this store only the date, and the SQL column value is a `Date` type)

Fact #2

I charge my table into a DataGridView (in the `Date` field it displays only a date)

Fact #3

I charge the DataGridView into a dataset datatable using the query

```
    datasets.DataSet1 ds = new datasets.DataSet1();
    datasets.DataSet1.DataTable1 dt = new datasets.DataSet1.DataTable1();

    for (i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count(); i++)
    {
        DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
        dRow["id"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        dRow["date"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add( dRow );
    }
```

Fact #4

If I put a breakpoint in this line

```
Row["date"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

the "Value" property displays (for example)

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = {13/05/2016 12:00:00 a.m.}
```

Fact #5 I have checked in my DataSet, and all values are System.String - type
and in SQL Server checking top 200 rows it is stored only the date 2016-05-13, and NOT any hour

You guys know where does the DataGridView takes that time value from?, when I open my dataset and datatable in my inform (.rdlc) it shows both date and time complements

Answer (score 0):

In .Net there is no 'Date' type like there is in Sql Server. In .Net there is only the [DateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For correct mapping data types read [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So internally, in every object that holds a Date value, there is a DateTime actually with default Time part of 00:00:00.000

Always have in mind that a DateTime value represents a moment in time.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only Date from DateTimePicker then You can do like this :

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

It means you have to call only `ToShortDateString();`

For more information you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098421/c-sharp-datetimepicker-how-do-i-get-the-date-in-the-format-1-1-2001) link.

Comment: that works when you work with a time handler like a dateTimePicker, but when I try to use that code line dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToShortDateString() it doesn't recognize it, do I have to add an aditional reference?

Comment: As you mentioned in "Fact #1" of your question that you store the value in SQL Server 2008 table like this "dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")", now change it this "dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()". Then after you don't have to convert that value to ToShortDateString() because it will automatically take only the date as input.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the DateTime  in the DataGridView column by using DefaultCellStyle property. Please refer to the below sample.

```
dataGrid.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Now when fetching date value from DataGridView Cell, convert the DateTime to date string.

```
var date=Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I hope this solves your problem.